# I can retrieve the contacts, but they are not displaying correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-widget

With this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ondemandandautomatic_dynamicauthorize);
LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this); 
llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 

LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
llp.weight = 1.0f;

// Contacts data snippet adapted from http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2011/05/contacts-api-20-and-above-android.html 
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
          String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
          String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

          CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext()); 
          cb.setText(id+name); 
          cb.setLayoutParams(llp); 
          llay.addView(cb);

        }
    }
// >Contacts data

ScrollView svh = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewHost);
svh.addView(llay);        

// One cat on stackOverflow said to do this, another said it would be unnecessary
svh.invalidate();
```

}

...and layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:text="@string/demand"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:text="@string/time"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:text="@string/space"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:text="@string/contact"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewHost"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

...I get what you can see here:

http://warbler.posterous.com/temporary-post-to-display-a-cosmetic-problem#

...so, the contacts are being retrieved, but the widgets are being plopped onto the emulator screen willy-nilly, or so it seems (and the ids/names are not displaying alongside the check boxes).

Updated:
I thought changing the code to the following might work, but it drops me into the Debug Perspective in Eclipse.

Is the problem that subsequent instantiations of widgets cannot have the same name as one already created (such as cbOnDemand)? If so, how can I get around this?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ondemandandautomatic_dynamicauthorize);

    ScrollView svh = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewHost);

    // Contacts data snippet adapted from
    // http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2011/05/contacts-api-20-and-above-android.html
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur
                    .getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            // Create a Linear Layout for each contact?
            LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this);
            llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            llp.weight = 1.0f;

            CheckBox cbOnDemand = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            cbOnDemand.setLayoutParams(llp);
            llay.addView(cbOnDemand);

            CheckBox cbTime = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            cbTime.setLayoutParams(llp);
            llay.addView(cbTime);

            CheckBox cbSpace = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            cbSpace.setLayoutParams(llp);
            llay.addView(cbSpace);

            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv.setText(id + name);
            tv.setLayoutParams(llp);
            llay.addView(tv);

            svh.addView(llay);
            // One cat on stackOverflow said to do this, another said it
            // would be unnecessary
            svh.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want your checkboxes+text in a single row? If not try to set  the orientation of the `LinearLayout` llay to `VERTICAL`.

Comment: Yes, I do want each row to have three checkboxes. For each contact, there should be three checkboxes and the contact name together on a row.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a number of TextViews - in your example you'll always be limited to 4. Instead use a ListView and you can add zero or many contacts to it. Here's an example of the xml (notice the id on the ListView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">    

<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.7" />

<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="0.7"              
         android:text="@string/noFriendsList"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

The TextView is only there to display some text when the list view is empty (also special id on it). In your code you'll need to create a class that extends the ArrayAdapter and set this as the adapter for the list view, e.g.:

```
ListView friendList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    initialiseList();
    friendList.setAdapter(mFriends);
```

where mFriends is my custom ArrayAdapter. There are plenty of examples of using the ArrayAdapter and the ListView online.

**Edit:** When you create your custom list adapter in your activity, like so:

```
mFriends = new FriendListAdapter(this, R.layout.friend_list_row, friendList);
```

you can use an xml layout which describes how each row should be laid out, and in your case should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/cb1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/cb2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cb1"/>

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/cb3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cb2"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/friendMobile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:textSize="12sp"             
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cb3" />  


</RelativeLayout>
```

I haven't tested this layout but it shouldn't be far away.

Comment: The four textViews I add in the layout xml are like a "header" - I always need just those four at that spot. In the dynamically created widgets, which get added to a ScrollView, there should be a row for each contact, and each of those rows should have three checkboxes and a textView (the Contact name).

Comment: I updated my original post with another attempt that is failing.

Comment: I originally tried to use a ListView, as that is the usual way to do something like this, but because I need three checkboxes for each line/row/contact, I couldn't get that to work. That's why I went down this path. It seems like it will work, but for now I'm stuck on the problem above.

Comment: I edited my original answer to show you how to use a layout for the rows which should give you 3 checkboxes and a textview for each row.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had something like this earlier, but can't determine a way to know which checkbox is being checked. I need to store the data, such as "ckbx1 for contact 1 is checked, ckbx2 for contact 1 is not checked," etc. I guess what I need to know with my latest attempt is to assign the contact id for each row to the checkbox's tag property (or some such; that's what it's called in other languages, and hopefully there is a Tag property in Java/Android, too).

Comment: I added this code:     cbOnDemand.setTag(id);
Theoretically, what I'm doing should work (I think); I've just got to figure out why it's not (duplicate names not allowed?)